# React child’s input onChange very slow

Tags: reactjs

I’m building a form with 24 inputs split into 3 children.

Parent

- Props -> Child 1

  o    Field 1 - onChange
- Props -> Child 2
- Props -> Child 3

I don’t know if I’ve done this correctly but if I update a text field on child 1’s field 1 using onChange which calls parent’s handleChange – it re-render all children on every keystroke – which is very expensive and very slow as each children have 8 inputs each.

Most of the example code works fine because they’re very trivial but when it starts to grow, maybe recommended approach doesn’t work?
Is there any other way to do this while maintaining controlled nature of my inputs? Seeing controlled component is a recommended way.

I do have redux but I wasn’t going to use it for each keystroke onChange, rather just use it for save, retrieve etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your child component should be [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)

Answer (score 1):

1. **Redux + Reselect might actually make it faster!** We use a big number of inputs (which removes the necessity of passing their state down in the component chain) with Redux/Reselect and actually directly setting the Redux state on change, and because Reselect prevents all the other components from rendering and going through the componenent chain, this in fact makes them more efficient.
2. **Remember that React Development Mode is [much, much slower than the Production Build](https://overreacted.io/how-does-the-development-mode-work/).** Try to test it out in Production mode and see how it behaves, if you have an average computer (if you do happen to have a high-end machine, do use Dev mode to measure speed).

Comment: You are right. prod build is a lot faster. but i'm still a bit dubious how it would behave when i finish the project though. For now. I'll look at managing local state in each of the groups for onChange value updates, and onblur of each input for updating parent state.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onBlur` for inputs instead of `onChange` if you do not need the instance changes to be updated.